# grep between two files using pattern

Tags: r

I have two files and I want to perform a grep where file1 is the pattern. I want to extract the lines from file2 matching the strings in file1. The strings from file1 are in the column: "Target.Gene" in file2. I am not sure how to use this type of patterns

file1

```
> head(a)
  symbol
1   AGER
2  TCF21
3  CLDN5
4   CDH5
5    CA4
6  RAMP3
```

file2

```
 > head(MTI)
      miRTarBase.ID           miRNA Species..miRNA. Target.Gene Target.Gene..Entrez.ID. Species..Target.Gene.
    1    MIRT006481 hsa-miR-181a-5p    Homo sapiens       DUSP6                    1848          Homo sapiens
    2    MIRT000002  hsa-miR-20a-5p    Homo sapiens       HIF1A                    3091          Homo sapiens
    3    MIRT000006 hsa-miR-146a-5p    Homo sapiens       CXCR4                    7852          Homo sapiens
    4    MIRT000006 hsa-miR-146a-5p    Homo sapiens       CXCR4                    7852          Homo sapiens
    5    MIRT006511 hsa-miR-200b-3p    Homo sapiens        RND3                     390          Homo sapiens
    6    MIRT006477  hsa-miR-328-3p    Homo sapiens       PTPRJ                    5795          Homo sapiens
                                                          Experiments          Support.Type References..PMID.
    1                         Luciferase reporter assay//Western blot        Functional MTI          17382377
    2 Luciferase reporter assay//Western blot//Northern blot//qRT-PCR        Functional MTI          18632605
    3                qRT-PCR//Luciferase reporter assay//Western blot        Functional MTI          18568019
    4                                                      Microarray Functional MTI (Weak)          20375304
    5                                       Luciferase reporter assay        Functional MTI          20683643
    6                                           qRT-PCR//Western blot        Functional MTI          22564856
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `merge` is what you need here. Does this give you the result you want:

```
mergedDat = merge(file1, file2, by.x="symbol", by.y="Target.Gene", all.x=TRUE)
```

This will return all rows of `file1` regardless of whether a given value in `file1` has a match in `file2`. If you only want rows with matches, just remove `all.x=TRUE`. See the help for `merge` for all the options regarding what the function does when there isn't a match.

Answer (score 2):

You might also find it straightforward to subset by indexing, and using the `%in%` operator.  The code below will filter MTI so that the result data frame has only the MTI rows where Target.Gene is one of the genes in a and all the columns.

```
result <- MTI[MTI$Target.Gene %>% a, ]
```